# Form validation within tabs assistance required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Please see a working demo of my form so far: [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh3z616n/)

I have it working so that if you do not fill in the fields it will not allow you to move onto the next tabs. However, if you fail to validate and then fill in the details the boxes stay red. I need some assistance with clearing the queried boxes once you fill them in.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var currentTab;
    $(".tabs-menu a, .tab-content .next").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            requiredAreFilled = true,
            tab = $this.attr("href") || $this.data('next'),
            currentTab = $('.tabs-menu .current').children('a').attr('href');
        $(currentTab).find('.required').each(function(index, elt) {
            if ($(elt).val() === '') {
                requiredAreFilled = false;
                $(elt).css('border', '2px solid #FB8183'); // This is bad, should be a class
            }

        });
        var tabLink = $this.is('a') ? $this.parent() : $('.' + tab.substring(1)),
            $tabLink = $(tabLink);
        console.log($tabLink);
        if (requiredAreFilled) {
            $tabLink.addClass("current")
                .siblings().removeClass("current");
            $(".tab-content").not(tab).hide();
            $(tab).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your JSFiddle repaired](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/gh3z616n/2/)

```
.required-error { /* new class */
    border: 2px solid #FB8183;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var currentTab;
    $(".tabs-menu a, .tab-content .next").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            requiredAreFilled = true,
            tab = $this.attr("href") || $this.data('next'),
            currentTab = $('.tabs-menu .current').children('a').attr('href');
        $(currentTab).find('.required').each(function (index, elt) {
            if ($(elt).val() === '') {
                requiredAreFilled = false;
                $(elt).addClass('required-error'); // This is bad, should be a class
            } else {
                /* this will fix the "corrected" inputs */
                $(elt).removeClass('required-error');
            }
        });
        var tabLink = $this.is('a') ? $this.parent() : $('.' + tab.substring(1)),
            $tabLink = $(tabLink);
        console.log($tabLink);
        if (requiredAreFilled) {
            $tabLink.addClass("current")
                .siblings().removeClass("current");
            $(".tab-content").not(tab).hide();
            $(tab).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger the keyUp event on the input fields to remove the border :)

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
  //remove the border
});
```

Y don't use a validation plugin, if you already use jQuery?

There are a lot of good Plugins out there:
http://formvalidator.net/

If you use Bootstrap i recommend: http://bootstrapvalidator.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [DEMO focusout](http://jsfiddle.net/gh3z616n/1/), [DEMO keyup](http://jsfiddle.net/gh3z616n/5/)

Basically this js is added :

```
    $(".tab-content").on("focusout",".invalidInput",function() {
        if($.trim($(this).val()).length>0)
            $(this).removeClass("invalidInput");
    });
```

and used a css class :

```
.invalidInput{
    border : 2px solid #FB8183;
}
```

This removes the border when the textbox focus is taken away, if you need it to happen as soon as user enters data, use `keyup` instead of `focusout`